# Enviar formulário sem saber o nome

Tags: javascript, funções

Tenho um formulário que muda o seu nome constantemente , e quero  dar o submit nele por uma função. Nesta função "altera" ele recebe o nome do formulário, mas desta forma que fiz ele não funciona. O "+ide+" do formulário é um numero aleatório, por isso passo ele para a função "altera". Se alguém poder me ajudar e explicar como fazer funcionar o que quero fazer.

```
<form method='get' action='GG.php' name='alteracao"+ide+"'>
    <button onclick='altera(alteracao"+ide+")'>Enviar</button>
</form>

function altera(ide){   
        document.ide.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Há um `'` faltando no onclick. Fora isso, não entendi o que você está tentando fazer. De onde é que vem o nome do formulário que sempre muda? Você está tentando descobrir qual é o nome ou tentando inventar um novo nome aleatório?

Comment: Esse  '  eu que esqueci quando fui escrever aqui. Esse "+ide+" ele muda sempre, por exemplo, ele pode ser "alteracao10" ou "alteracao55". Mas minha duvida fica sendo na própria função, ele funciona colocando document."ide".submit(); sendo que esse "ide" é o parâmetro que mimha função recebe?

Comment: Mas com vc faz a interação neste **"+ide+"**, já vem de algum lugar?

Comment: Como você esta gerando os formularios ?

Comment: Esse "+ide+" é gerado pelo banco de dados com um AutoIncrement, @LeAndrade

Comment: O `+ide+` é substituído por um número apenas na tag `form` ou também é na tag `button`?

Comment: Os formulário são gerado por um createElement + innerHTML. Que o createElement cria o lugar onde o formulário ira aparecer e o innerHTML coloca o formulário ja pre-criado no javacript. @MarcosJunior

Comment: @VictorStafusa na tag button o +ide" só é usado para enviar o parâmetro na função, assim enviando o nome exato do Form.

Comment: No caso aí não seria só pegar o valor do name? Pq o name já não vai vai com o valor do banco?

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de gerar um `name` aleatório para o formulário, gere um `id` aleatório:

```js
function altera(ide) {
    var form = document.getElementById(ide);
    alert(form.teste.value); // Para você se certificar que pegou o objeto correto.
    form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form method='get' action='GG.php' id='alteracao123'>
    <input name="teste" type="hidden" value="Segredo secreto!" />
    <button onclick='altera("alteracao123")'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

No exemplo acima, estou partindo do pressuposto de que 123 é o número gerado automaticamente.

Answer (score 1):

Pode obter o nome do form pela relação entre o botão e próprio form

```js
function altera(meuForm){
  alert(meuForm.name);
  meuForm.submit();
}
```

```html
<form method='get' action='GG.php' name="esse form tem um nome muito difícil"  id='alteracao"+ide+"'>
    <button type="button" onclick='altera(this.parentNode)'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Opa Obrigado , desta forma deu certo aqui.

Comment: Considere a resposta correcta e dê up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode dar um id para seu formulario como 'altera'

```
<form method='get' action='GG.php' name='alteracao"+ide+"' id="altera">
    <button onclick='altera(alteracao"+ide+")>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Com isso é possivel verificar quando for dar 'submit' no form e rodar sua função:

```
document.getElementById('altera').addEventListener('submit', function(
    // Aqui você realiza suas funções
    altera();
));
```

Comment: Há um problema , terei vários formulários que são gerados por javascript quando clico em um botão, assim posso ter vários formulários sem saber qual o Id deles, que cai na mesma duvida que tenho.

Comment: Tente definir uma class em padrão para eles, e colocar esse mesmo event listener com isso ele vai pegar o submit do form que foi enviado.

Comment: Mas o evento submit só ira acontecer pela própria função que fiz, estou usando a função para "forçar" o submit

Comment: Caso seja possível reformular sua pergunta, não entendi direito o que você quer saber para enviar para sua função, seria apenas esse ide?